# Is it possible to set a default setting in user pages for faster information retrieval?

Tags: feature-request, support

User pages have changed on Stack Overflow. Is there any setting to change it to the previous view format?

In the previous format, for example, after the first glance one can guess a user's primary field by simply looking at their first question and answer titles and also seeing their badges. But with the new look, for example if I want to see if a user has C# badges I should open the badges page, or if I want to see more questions I should open the questions page. In fact currently the page is full of items (summary pages) and some of them are not important (for me, like accounts, ....).

Comment: I posted customization of the user page as a feature-request feedback item at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113418/159508, linking to your question here.  You may want to go there and put in your own 2 cents, or upvote/downvote items as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say that

> **after the first glance one can guess a user's primary field** by simply looking at their first question and answer titles and also seeing their badges

remains true even with the new format:

[image: picutre of the asker's profile page, complete with obligatory freehand circle]

I'm guessing you're a c# / algorithm / .net kinda guy? With a little c++ in there too?

Comment: You are right AakashM, I asked this question exactly after I see changes, It wasn't very interesting for me, at that time I see accounts and badges and rep history is not useful, but currently I think at least accounts is useful.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any way to change layouts in the preferences. Considering the new changes were just rolled out, I'd give it a bit of time and see if there will be further changes or if you'll get used to the new layout. If many people are dissatisfied, I wouldn't be surprised if a user script or something similar pops up.